# How to fetch properties value in JSP as Boolean value for conditional check using Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurerconfiguration

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-form

## In my project we are using below configuration to the load configuration file in spring context.

```
<!-- Configuration property files -->
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName">
        <value>SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE</value>
    </property>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>jdbc.properties</value>
            <value>jms.properties</value>
            <value>config.properties</value>
            <value>override.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Later I want read config.properties as Boolean value in JSP Page. then based on conditions I want to rendered some comment box in UI.

Do have any work around on this. Please help me with your suggestion, Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't want that. Instead have the controller expose that boolean as a model attribute so that you can access it in your page. You can inject the value into the controller using `@Value`.

Comment: Thanks, @M.Deinum Actually I don't want to touch my controller class. is there any other way I can directly access these configuration value in JSP page through Spring config so in JSP can get boolean apply the condition check and render the comment box.

Comment: You could but you shouldn't. That really belongs in the controller, which prepares the model. Your JSP shouldn't depend on stuff in the application context.